# Is there any data limitation in sankey diagram plotted from excel sheet? Can anyone pls tell me

Tags: angular, typescript

[enter image description here][1]Is there any data limitation in Sankey diagram plotted from excel sheet? Can anyone pls tell me..
I am importing a excel sheet having 1300 rows data but I am able to plot only 12 rows data.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7BHx.png*strong text*

This is ts file
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAgXn.png

In console there is no error all the data is plotting but there is visibility issue

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68364445/19330634). Having negative values in your data can lead to this behavior.

Cheers

Comment: All the values are positive only. but still graph is not plotting. If I remove some rows data then graph is plotting properly .Can you pls tell me what I have to do

Comment: Since it's not a negative values issue, please try running your code with this sample dataset to check if the issue is data related : https://bost.ocks.org/mike/sankey/energy.json

Comment: See, What i'm trying to say, If it is data related issue then it should happen for all the data whatever is in excel sheet.. Ok...But it is happening only for that excel sheet which contains more than 30 rows data..
So my question is Is there any data limitation validation? Like 20 -25 rows data only can plot?
Thanks.

Comment: I have attached 1 image it is showing like this when importing a excel file with 100 numbers of data.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like you are the only one having this issue right now. Please provide code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I have attached code image Can you pls check,... Thanks